# youtube api PlayList generate (Title only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, playlist

**I have this big code:**

```
function _buildPlaylist() {
        //console.log('_buildPlaylist');

        _lastThumbOrientation=null;//important, make thumb holder every time on new playlist
        _playlistOpened=false;//reset for bottom this._autoOpenPlaylist selection

        var len = _videoProcessData.length, i = 0, thumb, div, _item, active_icon;
        //console.log('len = ', len);

        if(getDeeplinkData){
            dlink = baseURL + strict + firstLevel + '/';
            var str_to_filter, tempArr = categoryArr[activeCategory].mediaName;
        }

        for (i; i < len; i++) {
            //console.log(_item.description);

            _item = _videoProcessData[i];

            //deeplinks
            if(useDeeplink && getDeeplinkData){
                str_to_filter = filterAllowedChars(_item.deeplink);
                //console.log(str_to_filter);
                tempArr.push(str_to_filter);
            }

            playlistLength+=1;

            if(outputDeeplinkData){
                if(_item.type == 'local'){//aspect ratio always present
                    if(mp4Support){
                        loc_path = _item.mp4Path;
                    }else if(vorbisSupport){
                        loc_path = _item.ogvPath;
                    }else if(webmSupport){
                        if(_item.webmPath)loc_path = _item.webmPath;
                    }
                    if(loc_path.lastIndexOf('/')){
                        loc_name = loc_path.substr(loc_path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                    }else{
                        loc_name = loc_path;
                    }
                    deeplinkData.push({'id': playlistLength, 'name': loc_name, 'type':_item.type ,'video-id': loc_path, 'deeplink': dlink+_item.deeplink});
                }else{
                    deeplinkData.push({'id': playlistLength, 'name': _item.title?_item.title:'', 'type':_item.type ,'video-id': _item.id, 'deeplink': dlink+_item.deeplink});
                }
            }

            div = $('<div/>').addClass('thumbs').attr({'data-id': playlistLength-1, 'data-type': _item.type});
            if(thumbHolder)div.appendTo(thumbInnerContainer).bind('click', clickPlaylistItem);

            if(_item.type == 'local'){//aspect ratio always present
                div.attr({'mp4Path': _item.mp4Path, 'ogvPath': _item.ogvPath, 'webmPath': _item.webmPath?_item.webmPath:'', 'imagePath': _item.imagePath, 'data-aspectRatio': _item.aspectRatio});
            }else{
                div.attr('path', _item.id);
                if(currentObj.ytSizeSet){//if we have width and height, aspect ratio always present
                    div.attr({'data-width': currentObj.mediaWidth, 'data-height': currentObj.mediaHeight, 'data-aspectRatio': currentObj.aspectRatio});
                }
            }

            if(thumbHolder){
                //create thumb
                if(_item.thumbnail){
                    thumb=$(new Image()).addClass('thumb_img').appendTo(div).attr('alt', _item.title?_item.title:'').css({
                       cursor:'pointer',
                       opacity:0
                    }).load(function() {
                        //console.log($(this))
                        $(this).stop().animate({ 'opacity':1}, {duration: 500, easing: 'easeOutSine'});//fade in thumb
                    }).error(function(e) {
                        //console.log("thumb error " + e);
                    }).attr('src', _item.thumbnail);
                }

                //active icon
                active_icon = $(new Image()).appendTo(div).css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    display: 'none'
                }).load(function() {
                    //console.log(width,height);
                    $(this).css({
                        width: this.width,
                        height: this.height,
                        left: 50+'%',
                        top: 50+'%',
                        marginLeft: -this.width/2+'px',
                        marginTop: -this.height/2+'px'
                    })
                }).error(function(e) {
                    //console.log("error " + e);
                }).attr('src', ic_active_thumb);

                div.data('active_icon',active_icon);
            }

            _thumbHolderArr.push(div);//we need to have data to manipulate
        }

        checkPlaylistProcess();
    }
```

(It's a youtube api javascript code.
what it does is generate thumbnails with alt attribute title of the video .

What I want is to be generated only the title of the videos. without thumbnails.

**The code produces the following  html (with thumbnails)**

```
<div class="thumbInnerContainer" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 3500px;">

<div class="thumbs playlistSelected" data-id="0" data-type="youtube" path="tRe8JfAQmpI" data-width="640" data-height="360" data-aspectratio="2"><img class="thumb_img" alt="Accelerator after effects project file" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tRe8JfAQmpI/hqdefault.jpg"><img style="position: absolute; display: block; width: 37px; height: 37px; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -18.5px; margin-top: -18.5px;" src="data/icons/active_item.png">
</div>
<div class="thumbs" data-id="1" data-type="youtube" path="QeusWQ4LFmY" data-width="640" data-height="360" data-aspectratio="2"><img class="thumb_img" alt="After Effects Template Platform" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/QeusWQ4LFmY/hqdefault.jpg"><img style="position: absolute; display: none; width: 37px; height: 37px; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -18.5px; margin-top: -18.5px;" src="data/icons/active_item.png">
</div> 
<div class="thumbs" data-id="2" data-type="youtube" path="srGUFQwONXc" data-width="640" data-height="360" data-aspectratio="2"><img class="thumb_img" alt="Photo Album - After Effects Template" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/srGUFQwONXc/hqdefault.jpg"><img style="position: absolute; display: none; width: 37px; height: 37px; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -18.5px; margin-top: -18.5px;" src="data/icons/active_item.png">
</div>
</div>
```

**Now, this is what I want to generate.** (image alt Title attr Only, without thumbnails.)

```
<div class="thumbInnerContainer" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 3500px;">

<div class="thumbs playlistSelected" data-id="0" data-type="youtube" path="tRe8JfAQmpI" data-width="640" data-height="360" data-aspectratio="2">
  Accelerator after effects project file
</div>
<div class="thumbs" data-id="1" data-type="youtube" path="QeusWQ4LFmY" data-width="640" data-height="360" data-aspectratio="2">
   After Effects Template Platform 
</div>
<div class="thumbs" data-id="2" data-type="youtube" path="srGUFQwONXc" data-width="640" data-height="360" data-aspectratio="2">
    Photo Album - After Effects Template
</div>
</div>
```

**Note: Find these lines to see how it is generating the html**

```
//create thumb
                if(_item.thumbnail){
                    thumb=$(new Image()).addClass('thumb_img').appendTo(div).attr('alt', _item.title?_item.title:'').css({
                       cursor:'pointer',
                       opacity:0
                    }).load(function() {
                        //console.log($(this))
                        $(this).stop().animate({ 'opacity':1}, {duration: 500, easing: 'easeOutSine'});//fade in thumb
                    }).error(function(e) {
                        //console.log("thumb error " + e);
                    }).attr('src', _item.thumbnail);
                }
```

**How can I change to generate titles only, without thumbnails.?**

Comment: What's the question? (Notice this is a rhetoric question)

Comment: What happens is that generates thumbnails, what I want to do is to generate only titles. how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify this line.

```
div = $('<div/>').text(_item.title ? _item.title : '')....
```

And drop all of the `if` clause below which is generating two `<img/>` elements and appending them to the newly created `<div/>` element in `div`. Since you don't want it then you can just drop all of it.

```
if (thumbHolder) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: OMG! this is the solution!!!promptly and amazing. awesome >D  thank you Alexander, 're great.